# UNION multiple SELECT statements on same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to generate a view via UNION with multiple SELECT statements. Here are the SELECT statements:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `offline` FROM sensors WHERE mbits = 0 AND dirty = 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `active` FROM sensors WHERE dirty != 1;
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(mbits), 0) AS `bitrate` FROM sensors;
```

What I need is:

```
offline | active | bitrate
--------------------------
0       |10      | 57009
```

I've tried to UNION the first 2 SELECTS:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `offline` FROM sensors WHERE mbits = 0 AND dirty = 0
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `active` FROM sensors WHERE dirty != 1;
```

However, I get:

```
offline
-------
0 
10
```

I suspect that I might have to use a JOIN to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want [subselects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: why not just simple `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with 1 query by using `CASE WHEN`. You simulate the `COUNT(*)` by summing 1 when your condition is met.

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN mbits = 0 AND dirty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `offline` ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dirty <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `active` ,
       IFNULL(SUM(mbits), 0) AS `bitrate`
FROM sensors;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend conditional aggregation, but taking advantage of MySQL shortcuts;

```
SELECT SUM(  mbits = 0 AND dirty = 0 ) AS`offline,
       SUM( dirty <> 1 ) as active,
       COALESCE(SUM(mbits), 0) AS bitrate
FROM sensor
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively a not so efficient way of doing it,

```
SELECT offline,active,bitrate FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS offline FROM sensors WHERE mbits = 0 AND dirty = 0) offline_tab,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS active FROM sensors WHERE dirty != 1) active_tab,
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(mbits), 0) AS bitrate FROM sensors) sum_bits tab;
```